# NLTK dispersion_plot figure size

Tags: python, plot, nltk

How to change figure size in nltk dispersion_plot()?

Here is an example that I plotted below:

[image]

Comment: Do you use ipython or "normal" python shell?

Comment: Just normal one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `nltk` uses `matplotlib`, a simple change to `figsize` can be done:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))  # change figsize to (width, height), the size you want

# rest of code...
text1.dispersion_plot(['somehow', 'year', 'what'])
```

Comment: This answer does not work for the plot above.  Or if it does you answer is so incomplete as to be useless.  Please provide a complete answer.

Comment: Based on the change by @hongsy, I removed my down vote for his answer.  Thank you for enhancing it.  I tested it and showed it below with another example below.

Answer (score 0):

An enhanced answer that uses the NLTK Book example text3 (the Book of Genesis), but with a different plot title requires the use of the matplotlib OO-format syntax for the nltk method call (class member function), i.e., `nltk.draw.dispersion.dispersion_plot(text, word_list, title="Title Text")`, instead of `text3.dispersion_plot(word_list)`:

```
people_in_genesis = ["Adam", "Eve", "Noah", "God", "Abraham", "Sarah", "Isaac", "Joseph", "Jacob", "Saul"]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))  # change figsize to (width, height), the size you want

nltk.draw.dispersion.dispersion_plot(text3, people_in_genesis, title="Frequency of Words in Genesis")
```

Thank you.